# How does ghostscript convert PDF to .txt?

Tags: pdf, converters, ocr, ghostscript

GNU Ghostscript is able to convert pdf files to .txt (text files) in terminal.

```
gs -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o output.txt input.pdf
```

I was wondering how it accomplishes this task? Does it use OCR?

I'm not looking for a very hefty explanation, but just a push in the right direction (links to guides etc. would also do it).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't do OCR, and that's why it has limitations. It has multiple techniques and uses them in a heirarchical fashion:

- If the font has a ToUnicode CMap, use that to get the Unicode code
  points
- If not, then check the glyph names (if available) against a  standard
  list
- Assume the character codes are ASCII.

Since Ghostscript and the associated txtwrite device are open source, you can easily just read the source code for more information.